# How to use word Net with php

Tags: php, wordnet

how to use word Net with php is there is any interface or any class for it.....
i need to use wordnet for my dictionary purpose....

Answer (score 2):

On the download page there's a download available with a command line tool. You could use this from php if you have exec enabled.

http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#PHP) links to [this PHP API](http://www.foxsurfer.com/wordnet/) for WordNet.

Comment: In what way? It may come without documentation but the source is up at http://www.foxsurfer.com/wordnet/wordnet.php.tgz (it's a tarball)

Comment: wget http://www.foxsurfer.com/wordnet/wordnet.php.tgz
--2010-05-21 18:45:11--  http://www.foxsurfer.com/wordnet/wordnet.php.tgz
Resolving www.foxsurfer.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.foxsurfer.com'

Comment: Problem @ your end I suspect: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.foxsurfer.com/wordnet/

Comment: ya the problem is in my side but i dont know y is it happening like this do u know any other mirror or can u upload for me please.???

Answer (score 0):

yea I can't get it work - I have Windows though, looks to be UNIX favored - you also must download the old version of Wordnet. Might be easier to just use WordNet's command line.