# Parsing WordNet files with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordnet

I am trying to upload WordNet data to MySQL server using PHP. For that I am trying to parse the files I have downloaded from the WordNet site. Right now, I am using the code given below with unsatisfactory results:

```
$file='../type/noun.feeling';

$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle)
{
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $a = fgets($handle);

    $d=substr($a, 2, strlen($a)-4);
    preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', $d, $m);
    if($m){
    $e=$m[0];
    $p=preg_split('/\[(.*)\]/', $d);
    print_r($p); 
    echo '<hr>';
    $f=array();
    $buf="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($e);$i++){
    $l=$e[$i];
    if($l!=']'){if($l!='['){$buf.=$l;}}
    else{$f[]=$buf; $buf="";}
    }
    foreach($f as $g){
    $h=array();
    $h=explode(',', $g);
    print_r($h);
    echo '<br>';
    }
    }
    else{
    echo $d;
    }
    echo '<hr><hr><hr>';
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

Is there any available library for the same? Or if not, how can I parse the files better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use word Net with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882217/how-to-use-word-net-with-php)

Comment: Can you explain why your code is unsatisfactory? (Also, your intention is to go direct from wordnet file to HTML? Is putting a DB in the middle an option?)